# Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK transaction support with spring boot

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does Azure Cosmos DB support transaction Bach for Java SDK? for ACID operation. I know it has a support for .NET.I would like to use - Java with Cosmos DB mongoDB API, How do I implement transactional feature in this case. Any idea! If I am correct store procedures are specific to SQL API, not for mongoDB.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but yes the support is available. For details check this link out:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-cosmos-db-transactional-batch-support-for-java-sdk-470-and-above/

Comment: I know there isn't much to paste, but please cite important content of external pages with at date reference instead of just pasting a URL. If this URL becomes invalid nobody is able to see that the related feature is supported.